# Websocket calls are not reaching to middleware via ingressRoute in k8s

Tags: websocket, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress, helidon

I am trying to integrate traefik ingress route with middleware (forward-auth) for wss (secure websocket protocol).
For https requests ingressRoute works fine with forward-auth,
but for wss its not reaching to forward-auth, it's bypassing the middleware.

Tried many ingressRoutes with different pathprefix so that it can route to specific middleware which will forward to helidon app for authentication.
I am trying to setup ForwardAuth for wss incoming requests in traefik Ingress, but it's forwarding/bypassing to actual server without reaching to middleware, same thing works fine for usual https calls.

My websocket url: wss://ip:443/ws/guest

How to fix wss traffic for ingressRoute?

IngressRoute.yaml

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  name: traefik-tls
  namespace: sample-domain1-ns
spec:
  entryPoints:
   - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: PathPrefix(`/ws`)
    middlewares:
    - name: test-auth-tls
      namespace: sample-domain1-ns
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: sample-domain1-cluster
      port: 8001
  tls:
    certResolver: default
```

forward-auth.yaml

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-auth-tls
  namespace: sample-domain1-ns
spec:
  headers:
    customRequestHeaders:
      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
  forwardAuth:
    address:  https://sample-domain1-lb.sample-domain1-ns.svc.cluster.local:8080/auth
    tls:
       insecureSkipVerify: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this question with helidon, and while it's great if you're using Helidon I'm not seeing how your issue relates to Helidon specifically, rather than (as you described) ingress set-up, etc. Please correct me if I've missed a Helidon aspect here. And apart from that, I'm sorry, I don't have any suggestions for you.

Comment: yes. We are yet to reach to helidon. currently seems ingress route is causing issue

Answer (score 0):

It seem's like, some forward-auth configuration parameter's are require for websocket.

Please try with authRequestHeaders, authResponseHeaders (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/).